# Timezone can't be changed

Tags: 18.04, time, date, timezone

I am trying to fix an error in my timezone config on Ubuntu 18.04. When I go to the Date & Time control panel, no matter where on the map I click, it always says MDT (UTC-06).

Also did the following:

```
$ date
Wed Sep 19 18:34:35 MDT 2018
$ TZ='America/New York'
$ date
Wed Sep 19 22:34:56 America 2018
$ sudo date --set 18:35
Wed Sep 19 18:35:00 EST 2018
$ date
Wed Sep 19 22:35:00 America 2018
```

Even after this, the Date & Time control panel still shows MDT everywhere on the map.

Time on the Gnome menu bar is still 16:35 (the MDT time).

What's happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: I discovered that the TZ variable should have an underscore instead of a space: 'America/New_York'. This solves the problem of 'date' showing the wrong time zone. Editing the TZ line in ~/.profile makes the change permanent. Still no solution for the Date & Time control panel issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to change the time zone:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Mexico_City --adjust-system-clock
```

(Change 'America/Mexico_City' to the appropriate entry [from the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones))

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it via GUI

Try doing this as root provided you have access to it:

```
sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

Comment: This is the setting that got me in this situation. The man page for timedatectl says this: "Note that maintaining the RTC in the local timezone is not fully supported and will create various problems with time zone changes and daylight saving adjustments."